# How to Write text on map area coordinates

Tags: html, area

Is there any way to write text on  coordinates on image in html?
`<img src="img.png" width="300" height="45" usemap="#map">
<map name="map">
<area shape=""rect" coords='40,20,126,30'>`

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with a little CSS here is an example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img">

      <img src="" alt="" />

      <h4>Text you want to display on the image</h4>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img { 
   position: relative;//make the pozition of image relative 

}

h4 { 
   position: absolute; //and give absolute position to your text
   top: 200px; //this top and left values can be taken as coordinates of image 
   left: 0; 

}
```